Keep the same remote config even if the user changes device - firebase a/b
I don't quite understand if it's something that just occurred to me or if it's really hard to find the answer.
The problem is simple and basic, I have a firebase experiment that assigns variants of user A or B.
It seems that my users are using several devices and are failing the tests, so I was asked for a way to keep the same user variants no matter what device they are on.
so we can exemplify how

Pepe opens the application on an android device and creates an account in the app, which receives the variant A.
Pepe now logs in on an Ios device which receives variant b

how can I keep the same relationship between devices?
Or is this a bad practice for experiments and that is why it is not possible to do so?
by the way i am using firebase in react native, and the logins are with okta
to explain a little more my problem I can say that I use the experiment to show to some users a section of the app and to others the other part, and this user can see both depending on the phone he uses.

It is not bad approach to use in AB testing and your thoughts are correct. But firstly, I would dig into more real tracked data before this decision. I would find how many users from your user base have this pattern (using same app on different platforms). Upon this analysis you can do the action.
If you find that you need implement such a logic in your mobile app, I would recommend to use  "Import segments" Firebase feature. Basically you would need to start collect Firebase Installation ID, User ID (after login) and create the segment. Besides that you would need to build some SQL logic to get measured User ID from user's activity. Then your iOS and Android app need to be configured to assign feature flag value from Remote Config after user's login. You would need to join these two platforms based on User ID (after login). And after this implementation and testing, you need to create new AB test experiment and target only those users in this segment.
